# PHP 7 cURL request gives response code 302 nginx

Tags: php, apache, curl

```
$data = array(
                "data1" => "1000",
            );
    
            $data_string = json_encode($data);
    
            $ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/api/info/getPlan");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                "Content-Type: application/json",
                "Content-Length: " . strlen($data_string))
            );
    
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9fKn.png

I'm trying to make a POST request from the portal with the following code. And got above error in browser. I'm using PHP 7.4,Apache 2.4.6 version.

I see some answer say to use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION or cookies and I try it but I cannot figure out how to do. Please some help is really appreciated.

Comment: A 302 Found is a response code that tells you that what you requested was moved to a different URI. So bascally, you are trying to POST somewhere , where you should not

Comment: Ah, as JureW just said. This could be something as simple as adding a `/` at the end of the URL, so don't think the change has to be big.

Comment: It, maybe post to conf page to receive from another result page after

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is the correct answer
follow this example to see if it work for you

```
$cookie_file_path = "/toyourfile";
$data = array(
    "data1" => "1000",
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/api/info/getPlan");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); // if you run on commandline this will print out more information for you
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($data_string))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: using above code its gives :  {"status":"off","configured":false,"domain":"www.example.com"}.

Comment: I have made new server setup. and noted one case. using this url http://www.example.com/api/info/getPlan it not working. but when I use IP address its working. I have missed some configuration. Please suggest.